# RewriteRule rewrites to incorrect location

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using the Mod_Rewrite module to rewrite urls.

This is my RewriteRule:

```
RewriteRule ^index index.php
RewriteRule ^page page.php
```

If I'm going to localhost/page the content of page.php is shown. But when I go to localhost/index the url get rewritten to:

```
http://localhost/C:/Users/Username/Documents/Xampp/htdocs/index.php
```

Thank you.

**Edit:**
The full .htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^page page.php
RewriteRule ^index index.php
RewriteRule ^about about.php
RewriteRule ^contact contact.php
```

Comment: Check this out it may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162871/why-is-apaches-rewriterule-revealing-local-paths

Comment: Unfortunately this does not help. The strange thing is that 'localhost/page' and all other pages work but no 'localhost/index'.

Comment: I am wondering. Does the problem solve itself if you define `DirectoryIndex disabled`?

Comment: That is also not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problems like these are usually fixed by defining a `RewriteBase` ([docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase)). Put the following directive after the `RewriteEngine` directive, but before any rule you have:

```
RewriteBase /
```

Comment: Do you have any other rules other than these two? If so, please copy over the entire `.htaccess` into your question by using the edit link under your question.

Comment: Done, the full .htaccess file is now in the question-post.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is adding the `[L]` flag to every rule, but I don't think that *should* make a difference. I can't try to reproduce this until I get home though.

Comment: all I could think would be to change the `RewriteRule`s to `RewriteRule ^index$ index.php`

Comment: @Jhecht I would expect a 500 internal server error if multiple matches were the problem. It can't hurt adding the `$` though.

Comment: The RewriteBase was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try these rules with anchors `$`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^page/?$ page.php [L]
RewriteRule ^index/?$ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^about/?$ about.php [L]
RewriteRule ^contact/?$ contact.php [L]
```

Alternatively you can try this line on top of your .htaccess:

```
Options +MultiViews
```

Comment: Did you use `Options +MultiViews` line on top of your .htaccess?

Comment: Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not?

Comment: Yes, it do. /page, /contact and all other urls are working. But /index not.

Comment: Do you see `/C:/Users/Username/Documents/Xampp/htdocs/index.php` in your browser?

Comment: localhost/C:/Users/Username/Documents/Xampp/htdocs/index.php is the URL in the browser.

Comment: Than it is working! Thank you, the problem was in the cache. It is working with the RewriteBase /.