# .htaccess always redirects to a folder

Tags: .htaccess

I would like to create an installation folder, before the installation the `.htaccess` in the main folder may redirect always to the installation folder.

The url could be:

```
http://server.com/somefolder/mainFolder/someFileOrFolder.ext
redirects to
http://server.com/somefolder/mainFolder/install/

http://server.com/mainFolder/someFileOrFolder.ext
redirects to
http://server.com/mainFolder/install/
```

SomeFolder is unknown

I tried something in the `.htaccess` file but I couldn't solve.

**EDIT:** I forgot to say that mainFolder is where the .htaccess is and its name is also unknown.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, this should be what you want. You'll need to make sure `mod_rewrite` is installed on your server (speak to your hosting company if you're unsure). This would go into your `.htaccess` in the root directory. [Mod_rewrite reference](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]*)/mainFolder/(.*)$ ./$1/mainFolder/install/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^mainFolder/(.*)$ ./mainFolder/install/ [R=301,L]
```

The first rule is for whenever `mainFolder` is inside another folder. I've assumed that a folder name is only letters (upper- and lowercase) and numbers. If there are other characters that may be present you can just modify `([a-zA-Z0-9]*)`. The brackets are needed to group everything before `mainFolder` into the variable `$1`.

The second rule is for when `mainFolder` is in the root directory.

It's possible to create one rule to replace these two rules but this is a simple solution that should work for you.

[URL Rewriting Guide](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html)

**EDIT:** If you want to check whether the installation has already happened before redirecting, you wouldn't be able to use this method. You'd have to check whether the install had happened in whichever scripting language you use (e.g. PHP) then redirect in that language.

Comment: Using the rules that you said, I doesn't get any result because as I've edited in my original question, the mainFolder is wich contains the .htaccess.

I've adapted this rules and I get the same result of some test I've made before.

**.htaccess**

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]*)/?(.*)?$ .$1/install/ [R=301]`

**Result**
`http://localhost/basico/
is redirected to
http://localhost/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/basico/install/`

Where basico is the mainfolder.

Comment: If you are putting a `.htaccess` into a folder it's not unknown because you know where you are putting the file when you upload it. If you have a different set of requirements for each folder depending on where the folder is situated and you have a different `.htaccess` file in each folder then you can make the contents of the `.htaccess` different in each file.

Comment: And what about the redirection is adding the real local path of Where server files are?

Comment: I've amended the answer with an extra `RewriteBase /` which may help. Also, try without the `.` in `./mainFolder/install/`. From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162871/why-is-apaches-rewriterule-revealing-local-paths).

Comment: If i use `RewriteBase /` the result is 'http://localhost/install/` it may be 'http://localhost/basico/install` the .htaccess is inside basico folder and removing de `.` the result is also wrong